# Practical difference between S3 presignedUrl and signing authorization header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on an application that needs to access some private S3 objects over http. This application will be running in ECS with appropriate access to get the s3 objects. The generated http url is used for machine-machine communication, not be an end user.

My initial thought was to use a presigned URL but I'm now reading about signing the request using an `Authorization` header. Are there any practical differences between the two different approaches? Would there be any performance differences in the different approaches?

From what I can see the end result is the same, it's just the method of how the Authorization credentials are passed that differ?

Comment: It's the same signature and verification logic, using a presigned URL just means that the client has one URL to deal with rather than breaking making a request with different headers.  That tends to be easier to implement from a client perspective, they just make a HTTPS request with a URL like they normally do, but at the end of the day, they're basically the same request.

Comment: Thanks @AnonCoward - that's what I thought but wanted to double check I wasn't missing something that was fundamentally different.